# Multiple classes in frameworks warning

Tags: xcode, frameworks, warnings

I just started seeing the following warning in Xcode's console:

```
Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace (0x12f3384d0) and    

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference (0x12e464e38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I'm not familiar with the above framework and I'm not using any frameworks in the little app I'm experimenting with.

I don't know why this started showing up unless I did something by accident and I don't remember.

Any clues as to what the cause is?

thanks

Comment: Hopefully you'll get a more definitive answer, but my understanding is that this is a known problem in iOS and Apple has been working to fix it and that unfortunately the best you can do right now is ignore it unless one of the symbols is actually in your code (which it isn't in this case). I see this constantly and haven't been able to clear it.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the comment. it is certainly a strange one! will ignore it for now. thanks again.